# Dense subset for $C_0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I want to know if $\left\{\frac{(1-\cos \alpha x)} {x^2}\right\}_{\alpha>0}$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R})\mid \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0\}$?  That is, for any $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varepsilon >0,$ there is some $\alpha_1>0,\alpha_2>0,\cdots,\alpha_n>0$ and $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \left| f(x)-\sum_{k=1}^na_k\frac{(1-\cos \alpha_k x)} {x^2} \right| <\varepsilon.$$

Comment: They are all even functions AFAICT.

Comment: I think this is near duplicate to [dense subset of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045778/dense-subset-of-continuous-functions). Just some linear combinations in $C_0(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $f_a$ considered are (up to a multiplicative constant) the Fourier transforms of even tent functions. The real linear combinations of even tent functions yield all even continuous and piecewise affine real functions with compact support, which are dense in the even integrable real functions for the $L^1$-norm. Hence, the **vector space spanned by the functions** $f_a$ is dense in the subspace of all even real functions of $\mathcal{F}L^1$, which is dense in subset of all even real functions $\mathcal{C}_0$.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, due to evenness it is more natural to consider functions on the closed right half line.  The result then follows from the generalised Markushevish duality theom applied to the function of two variables $x$ and $\alpha$.  This is worth mentioning since it shows that you don't hsve to use all $\alpha$--it suffices to take a sequence thereof  provided that it has a positive limit point

Comment: Reference for Markushevish: Studia Math. 33 (1969) 15€-164.  (Apologies--this is a comment on the question, not the above answer).